# How does loss extracly work in keras when using train_on_batch?

Tags: python, keras

I am confused about loss in keras when using 'train_on_batch'.
See my model below (a implementation of triplet)
Sometimes my model outputs Nan, and the loss still shows something like 0.4.
And after some iterations, the encoder always shows the same output regardless what the input is.
And in that situation the loss of the triplet model should be 0.5 (see function bpr_triplet_loss below), but keras tells the loss is something like 0.1 or 0.2, even sometimes greater than 1 or smaller than 0. Why?
Is it because gradient exploding problem occurs and then the model is broken?

```
    ter_input = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
    ter_input_pos = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
    ter_input_neg = Input(shape=self.img_shape)

    ed = self.encoder()
    ter_encoded = ed(ter_input)
    pos_encoded = ed(ter_input_pos)
    neg_encoded = ed(ter_input_neg)

    def bpr_triplet_loss(X):
        positive_item_latent, negative_item_latent, user_latent = X
        # BPR loss
        loss = 1.0 - K.sigmoid(
            K.sum(user_latent * positive_item_latent, axis=-1, keepdims=True) -
            K.sum(user_latent * negative_item_latent, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
        return loss

    loss_layer = Lambda(bpr_triplet_loss, output_shape=(1,))([pos_encoded, neg_encoded, ter_encoded])

    def identity_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(y_pred - 0 * y_true)

    self.triplet_net = Model(
        input=[ter_input, ter_input_pos, ter_input_neg],
        output=loss_layer)
    self.triplet_net.compile(loss=identity_loss, optimizer=Adam(0.0001, beta_1=0, beta_2=0.99, decay=0.00001))  # Adam()
```